# Why is adding background music to video using `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i music.mp3 output.mp4` not working?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I explored google and StackOverflow for how to add background music to the video and many of them suggested to use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -shortest output.mp4
```

I have been trying to achieve this but it just does not work. When I try to add map like

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -i bg.mp3 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 oo.mp4
```

The video sound is replaced by the bg.mp3

And if I try `-map 0 -map 1:a:0` or not provide map, the audio is not added at all.

How do I add the background music? I don't also get any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-map` is a selector; select a type of stream from an input "file". To merge two audio streams, you need an audio filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -lavfi "[0:a][1:a]amerge[out]" -map 0:v -map [out]:a -shortest output.mp4
```

- `-lavfi`: Same as `-filter_complex`, because you have two inputs
- `[0:a][1:a]` take audio stream from the first and second inputs
- `-map 0:v` select the video stream from the first input without processing
- `-map [out]:a` select the audio stream from the `filtergraph` (processed)

The shortest option in the `amerge` filter is set by default.

If you have problems, you might want to check also the `amix` filter, the audio codecs of your files, and the volume filter to adjust the volume of the inputs in the `filtergraph`.

Additional references:

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge
- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix
- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is there a way to control the volume of the background music?

Comment: to decrease the volume ...."[1:a]volume=-3[a1];[0:a][a1]amerge[out]".....

Answer (score 0):

If the video length is longer than music you can add "-stream_loop -1" to repeat music until end of video

```
ffmpeg -i video_with_audio.mkv -stream_loop -1 -i background_music.mp3 -lavfi "[0:a][1:a]amerge[out]" -map 0:v -map [out]:a -shortest video_with_audio_and_background_music.mkv
```

If you want increase or decrease the volume, follow this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video_with_audio.mkv -stream_loop -1 -i background_music.mp3 -lavfi "[1:a]volume=0.2,apad[A];[0:a][A]amerge[out]" -map 0:v -map [out]:a -shortest video_with_audio_and_background_music.mkv
```